# Adding new column with same name continously with PHP and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I want to add new rows to my table each time I enter information to my table. But first, I automatically have to open new columns.

```
$Connection=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','database');

    $Query="ALTER TABLE `koli_stok_hareketleri` 
    ADD `uretilen_koli` INT(11) NOT NULL AFTER `koli_adet`, 
    ADD `tarih` VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL AFTER `uretilen_koli`;";

    $Execute=mysqli_query($Connection,$Query)
    or die("Bad Query: $Query");

   if($Execute){
          $_SESSION["SuccessMessage"]= " Works";

                 } else {
       $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]= "Doesnt Work";

                        }
```

*What I need to do is:* checking last inserted column here: **'tarih'** and then make two new columns as **'uretilen_koli1'** and **'tarih1'** then go on with the same system as user adds new information like **'uretilen_koli2'** and **'tarih2'**

What is the way of producing new columns regarding to the last column number/value automatically ?

```
$Connection=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','database');
    $ViewQuery="SHOW COLUMNS FROM koli_stok_hareketleri";
    $result=mysqli_query($Connection,$ViewQuery);
    while($ColumnNames=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

        $LastColumnName = $ColumnNames['Field'];
        $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]= "$LastColumnName";


    }
```

I can get the last column with this way but now I need to loop it.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by simply eliminating the string.

```
    $Connection=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','database');
    $ViewQuery="SHOW COLUMNS FROM koli_stok_hareketleri";
    $result=mysqli_query($Connection,$ViewQuery);
    while($ColumnNames=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    $LastColumnName = $ColumnNames['Field'];
    $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]= "$LastColumnName";   }


    $NewColumnNameKoliAdet=$LastColumnName+1;
    $NewColumnNameTarih=$LastColumnName+2;

    $Connection=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','database');
    $Query="ALTER TABLE `koli_stok_hareketleri`
    ADD `$NewColumnNameKoliAdet` INT(11) NOT NULL AFTER `$LastColumnName`,
    ADD `$NewColumnNameTarih` INT(11) NOT NULL AFTER `$NewColumnNameKoliAdet`;";

   $Execute=mysqli_query($Connection,$Query)
    or die("Bad Query: $Query");
        if($Execute){
          $_SESSION["SuccessMessage"]= " Works";

                 } else {
       $_SESSION["ErrorMessage"]= "Does Not Work"; }
```